# .post Node.js/Express/Mongoose call, not saving posts (.save) after the first post.. Further updated, Closures Issue?

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

With AJAX/Node.js/Express/Mongoose/MongoDB, the data is being delivered successfully over ajax to node.js and is logging properly, but only the first post is being saved in MongoDB..

Sending posts after the first post still logs all the new data, but the console gets held on an empty line (the cursor just stands still)..after the 'post success!' console.log, which follows the .save call, but the db doesn't receive that new data!?

Only after refreshing the webpage, or saving the file (nodemon auto-starts thereafter), does a new post save.

Here's the console log (the '|' on the last line represents the hanging cursor..):

```
Server is starting
posting a new Message..from: 53aada6f8b10eb0000ec8a90
[ 'username1' ]
element: username1
To: username1
Message: testTwo
Created: Tue Jul 01 2014 15:53:57 GMT-0400 (EDT)
post success!
|
```

And here's the Node.js/Express/Mongoose .post & .save:

```
router.route('/messages')

// create a message (accessed by POST @ http://localhost:4200/api/v1/messages)
.post(function(req, res) {

    console.log('posting a new Message..from: ' + req.session.user );

    var message = new Models.Message();

    var toWhom = req.body.to;

    console.log(toWhom); // [ 'user1', 'user2' ]

    toWhom.forEach(toWhomLoop);
    function toWhomLoop(element, index, array) {

    console.log('element: ' + element); // 'user1'

        message.to.push({

            user : user,
            username : element,
            read :
            {
                marked : false,
                datetime : null
            },
            updated : req.body.nowDatetime

        }); // push: to MessageUserSchema [array]

    }

    message.from.push({

        user : req.session.user,
        username : req.session.username,
        updated : req.body.nowDatetime

    }); // push: from MessageUserSchema [array]

    message.message = req.body.message;
    message.created = req.body.nowDatetime;

    console.log('To: ' + req.body.to);
    console.log('Message: ' + req.body.message);
    console.log('Created: ' + req.body.nowDatetime);

    // save the message, and check for errors
    message.save(function(err) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Message "' + message.message + '" Created' });

    });

    console.log('post success!');

})
```

Upon a further look, and with *sublime* highlighting the closures.. the .post(function(req, res) { closures `({ })` don't highlight on either side (start or end), except when the following elements are cut from the .post:

```
    message.from.push({

        user : req.session.user,
        username : req.session.username,
        updated : req.body.nowDatetime

    }); // push: from MessageUserSchema [array]

    message.message = req.body.message;
    message.created = req.body.nowDatetime;

    console.log('To: ' + req.body.to);
    console.log('Message: ' + req.body.message);
    console.log('Created: ' + req.body.nowDatetime);
```

Only when **all** the above is commented/cut from the .post the closures highlight.. Is there a syntax issue?

Comment: Are you closing your mongoose connection somewhere?  That will make a query hang.

Comment: @JohnnyHK what might that look like?

Comment: For instance, calling `mongoose.disconnect();` somewhere after the first post would cause this.

Comment: @JohnnyHK disconnect isn't called anywhere in the app..

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for taking a look at this.. have further isolated the issue, and have updated the question accordingly, if you're up to take another look.. very grateful

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code but that might be my problem not yours. Anyway, isn't there any error that it can hang on ? I'm not sure if node sends errors to console log by default. One problem might be that you are pushing to message.from and it might be that it is not an array, so it will throw an error. Also this doesn't make much sense: you are pushing to `message.from` as to an array and right after that you are overwriting it with `message.from = req.body.from;`...It might be that in next loop it is not an array cause req.body.from was not and it hangs on error, until you restart node

Comment: @Krym thanks for the comment.. Basically, I call the Mongoose Model, loop through the toWhomArray to push to the array of embedded 'to' docs, then push the logged in user to the array of embedded 'from' docs, then set some upper level values, and .save .. if it were a save error, the if err for .save should catch it, but there's no error..it just hangs, and then eventually continues on to some session checking code.. btw, the message.from was clipped from previous code, pardon any confusion there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `save()` function to:

```
// save the message, and check for errors
message.save(function(err, result) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
    }
    console.log("The result: ", result);
    res.json({ message: 'Message "' + message.message + '" Created' });

});
```

Comment: Isn't this functionally the same, but with logging?

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes, but the logging pointed to the error, which was what I needed.. guess I didn't know where to look for the res.send(err) info..

Comment: @StackThis Cool, glad you figured it out.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Appreciate that